# php what is the equivalent of preg_match but does not require regex?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, str-replace

In PHP is there an equivalent to `preg_match` that does not require the use of regex? There is `str_replace()` for `preg_replace`. Is there something for `preg_match`.

*update * I am only looking to replace a known string with another. Using regex just seems like overkill.

I have the string "This is a [test1], and not a [test2]" and I want to match them with "[test1]" and "[test2]".

Comment: Where regex is required you have to use regex

Comment: `str_replace` is not an equivalent for `preg_replace`. Their purpose is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean *find a string within another string without using regex*, you can use [strpos](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos('hello today', 'hello') !== false) {
    // string found
}
```

Comment: +1 because I only understood the question after I read your answer

Answer (score 1):

Since I am not sure what result you are looking for I can't say if this is exactly what you are looking for.

You can use [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to see if an occurrence of one string is in another.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question there is some function of PHP without regex

> Do not use preg_match() if you only
>   want to check if one string is
>   contained in another string. Use
>   strpos() or strstr() instead as they
>   will be faster.

But they can not replace `preg_match` completely at all

Answer (score 0):

First, `str_replace()` **is not replacement** for `preg_replace()`. Function `str_replace()` replaces all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string, preg_replace() replaces content selected by regular expressions (that's not same thing).

A lot of things require regex (and that's good) so you can't simply replace it with single PHP function.

Comment: `str_replace` is the replacement for `preg_replace` when you are only looking to replace an occurrence of one string in another.

Comment: @MitMaro, in that one single case, YES. But generally, that's not true at all. Try to match more complicated pattern with str_replace() and replace it with something else, than just trying to replace A with B. Agree with you, it's true what you say.

Comment: I am under the assumption that is what the OP was looking for. Hard to say without more details though.

Comment: @MitMaro, Agree again, hard to say... but according to this question he is looking for alias functions that doesn't require regex. And surely, str_replace() is not alias of preg_replace().

Answer (score 0):

Most developers use preg_match because they want to use the matches (the third parameter which will get set by the function).

I can not think of a function that will return or set the same information, as done with matches.

If however, you are using preg_match without regex then you might not care as much about the matches.

If you are using preg_match to see if there is a "match" and just that then I'd suggest using **strpos** instead, since it is much more efficient at seeing if one string is found in another.